# Error on event click + Getting data from database

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to run an event, but when I run it, I get the error:

> The expression On Click you entered as the event property setting
>   produced the following error: The Expression you entered has a
>   function containing the wrong number of arguments.
>
> - The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure].
> - There may have been an error evaluating the function, even, or macro.

I'd use the following code:

```
    Public Function CH05_Generate(Sagsnr As String)

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim Doc As Word.Document
Dim WordPath As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set db = CurrentDb
sql = "SELECT * FROM Projektdata WHERE Sagsnr Like '" & Sagsnr & "'"
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)


WordPath = "My path (Can't show this"

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Doc = WordApp.Documents.Add(WordPath)

With Doc
    .FormFields("PName").Result = rst![Projektnavn]
    .FormFields("text").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!Kommentar
    .FormFields("S3").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q1
    .FormFields("S4").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q2
    .FormFields("S5").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q3
    .FormFields("S6").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q4
    .FormFields("S7").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q5
    .FormFields("S8").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q6
    .FormFields("S9").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q7
    .FormFields("S10").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q8
    .FormFields("S11").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q9
    .FormFields("S12").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q10
    .FormFields("S13").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q11
    .FormFields("S14").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q12
    .FormFields("S15").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q13
    .FormFields("S16").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q14
    .FormFields("S17").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q15
    .FormFields("S18").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q16
    .FormFields("S19").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q17
    .FormFields("S20").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q18
    .FormFields("S21").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q19
    .FormFields("S22").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q20
    .FormFields("S23").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q21
    .FormFields("S24").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q22
    .FormFields("S25").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q23
    .FormFields("S26").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q24
    .FormFields("S27").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q25
    .FormFields("S28").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q26
    .FormFields("S29").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q27
    .FormFields("S30").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q28
    .FormFields("S31").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q29
    .FormFields("S32").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q30
    .FormFields("S33").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q31
    .FormFields("S34").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q32
    .FormFields("S35").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q33
    .FormFields("S36").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q34
    .FormFields("S37").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q35



End With

WordApp.visible = True
WordApp.Activate
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, True

End Function
```

What I want to achieve to get data from the "Projektdata" database, and get the correct data, "Projektnavn", to fill out:

```
 .FormFields("PName").Result = rst![Projektnavn]
```

My database structure is like this:
[image]

Comment: From the error message, the problem is how you **call** your function. How do you do that? Is it directly in an event property? e.g. `=CH05_Generate(foo, bar)` ?

Comment: ms access or sql server?

Comment: I call my function like this: `=CH05_Generate()`

Comment: Where do `Sagsnr` and `ItemID` come from? Are they fields on your form too (like `Kommentar`)?

Comment: No they are not. I have many "Projektnavn", and they all have a Sagsnr. I've edited my question so you can see how the database is structured.

Comment: Also I modified the query and deleted ItemID

Comment: Ok, that's a little clearer, but the question remains: where does this parameter come from: `(Sagsnr As String)` ? Something on your forms or tables or code must determine the correct `Sagsnr` to use?

Comment: This can be me who is really confused, I haven't been working much with query and VBA in general. Since I have many "Projektnavn", I have to do some sort of lookup or something else to find the right "Projektnavn" Earlier today I made it find the first "Projektnavn" in the database, but not the right one.

Comment: If you don't know how to find the correct `Sagsnr`, this might be a hint that your table structure is wrong (specifically the `Projektdata` table). But only you can answer that. --- Since the original question was answered, you might consider accepting an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT *
FROM dbo.Projektdata p
JOIN dbo.Items i ON p.Sagsnr = i.Sagsnr
WHERE ItemID =" & ItemID & " AND p.Sagsnr Like '" & Sagsnr & "'" -- change "," to AND
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to change that back. I still get the same message though.

Answer (score 0):

> I call my function like this: `=CH05_Generate()`

```
Public Function CH05_Generate(Sagsnr As String, ItemID As String)
```

This cannot work - the function expects two parameters, you need to pass them in the function call.

Comment: So I have to call it like: `=CH05_Generate(Sagsnr As String, ItemID As String)` ?

Comment: @Uppah: No, you have to supply the values. If these are text boxes on your form, you can try `=CH05_Generate([Sagsnr], [ItemID])`. Or maybe you need to explain in more detail, what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: What I want to achieve, is to generate a word template by clicking the button. I need something from the "Projektdata" database/table, so I have to "connect" to it, but I seem to get errors on errors.